# Migrating scheduled tasks from ColdFusion 8 to ColdFusion 10

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-8

I have several Apache / ColdFusion 8 servers installed on a Linux Red Hat platform. I migrated those to an IIS / ColdFusion 10 Update 12 / Windows 2012R2 environment.
I installed the ColdFusion 10 server first, updated it to update 13. Then I imported the ColdFusion 8 server settings using a CAR file. That succeeded but we have problems with the imported scheduled tasks data in ColdFusion 10:

1. they seem to run even though they are stopped;
2. when inspecting the `C:\ColdFusion8\lib\neo-cron.xml` with `C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\lib\neo-cron.xml` file I see a difference:

ColdFusion 8 uses these keys for scheduled task pausing:

```
paused      true    Task is paused
paused      false   Task is running
```

ColdFusion 10 uses these keys for scheduled task pausing:

```
Status      Paused      Task is paused
Status      Running     Task is running
```

Don't the keys have to be equal (key `paused` transformed to `Status` during import) in order for ColdFusion server to be able to handle them?

Is this the correct way to transfer CFAdmin settings from a lower ColdFusion version to a higher version? What about the option to "do you want to import settings" at the end of the ColdFusion 10 install process.. is that equivalent to deploying CAR files?

Comment: It is usually the correct way, but CF 10 dropped JRun for Tomcat and I think there's an entirely new scheduled task engine under the hood. It's likely the case that CF is translating values as needed during the import.